# Why CursorWindow column is equal to -1?

Tags: android, sqlite

I an trying to run my first database connected program and here is the problem that I face.

```
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.
```

This is the  error that I get when showData() function is called which I guess means that it is trying to get the the first elements value from row 0 and column -1.

Why do it starts from - 1 and how to make it start from column = 1
     package com.example.garegin.data;

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
String fName, sName, mail;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB1",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(fName VARCHAR, sName VARCHAR, mail VARCHAR);");

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addData(view);
        }
    });

    Button list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showData(view);
        }
    });

}

private void addData(View view){
    EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sname);
    EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
    fName=text1.getText().toString();
    sName=text2.getText().toString();
    mail=text3.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO  Student VALUES('"+fName+"', '"+sName+"', '"+mail+"')");
}

private void showData(View view){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Student", null);
    int count = c.getCount();
        c.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
        tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        TableRow tableRow;
        TextView textView,textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        textView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("Firstname");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tableRow.addView(textView);

        textView4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView4.setText("LastName");
        textView4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView4.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView4.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tableRow.addView(textView4);

        textView5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView5.setText("Email");
        textView5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView5.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView5.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tableRow.addView(textView5);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

        for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fName")));
            textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sName")));
            textView3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mail")));

            textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


            tableRow.addView(textView1);
            tableRow.addView(textView2);
            tableRow.addView(textView3);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            c.moveToNext() ;
        }
        setContentView(tableLayout);
        db.close();

}
public void close(View view){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: check that after `c.moveToFirst();` cursor count is not empty before using any data from it

Comment: Sorry, but can you clarify what exactly to check?  Do, you mean to put int coursor after c.moveToFirst(); ??

Comment: after `c.moveToFirst();` check if `c.count()` is greater than 0. You can `DEBUG` it or add an `if statement` there. Probably you are getting empty cursor and it crashes after you try to set data using an empty cursor

Comment: Do you mean c.getCount()??

Comment: yeah, the error is shown as your `cursor` is empty

Comment: Really?? I was thinking that the error is about accessing to -1 col! But I will check now

Comment: Same error,      Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Comment: Debug and you will find the error. Also check column names if they are right

Answer (score 3):

When you call `getColumnIndex()`, you'll get index -1 for those column names that are not there in the `Cursor`. Attempting to retrieve a value on the first row column index -1 produces the error.

Make sure the column names you're referencing are there in your query.

---

Edited after the code was added: Seems like you have an older version of the database file around without all the . `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` won't create the table if a table with the same name already exists. The old table doesn't have the columns you're trying to access. To fix it, remove the old database: either uninstall your app, or use the app manager to clear its data.

Comment: Yes they are in query!! I have checked it right now

Comment: If you need further help with it, consider posting your code in the question.